# React-redux add a new variable to state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am struggling to get working on a React-redux application to pass a value via the state from one component on to another. I do not wish to use the reducer and/or dispatch because I am not calling a webservice, I just want to take a value from a textbox form to enable another control on the order component.

Firstly, I can grab the value from control,  but when mapstatetoprops is called the variable I set and wish to add to the state is undefined. This also possibly explains why my other problem. On my other component the function to use props is never called because of the state-componentWillReceiveProps

Here is the relevant code snippet :

```
<ListItemContent>
    <Control component={Textfield} model="somemodel" label="MyLabel" onBlur={this.onChangeOfValue}/>
</ListItemContent> 

onChangeOfValue = (event) => { 
    this.setState({ 
        newValueToPassAlong: event.target.value
    }); //newValueToPassAlong is set in constructor 
};

let mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
    return {
        newValueToGive: state.newValueToPassAlong
    } // This is undefined
}; 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(form)
```

So, my question is how do add a new variable to a state using React-redux without the need of reducers,  etc and with this can I access this variable in my  other component?

Comment: What's wrong with using an action creator/reducer with non-networked actions? That said, read this for a potential solution. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: It feels a lot to do when all I need to know if a value has been entered in the textbox,  plus the code I have inherited is using saga which seems to have a bug in it

Comment: if you use redux, actions and reducers are your tools of the trade.

Answer (score 3):

Ok action creator preferences aside, if you want to sync something between two components which share a common parent, you have to bring that state into the parent.

```
class ParentComponent {
    onItemChanged = (newData) => {
        this.setState({ thing: newData });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildA onItemChanged={ this.onItemChanged } />
                <ChildB thing={ this.state.thing } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

when you change the value in `ChildA`, use `this.props.onItemChanged` with the new value. In `ChildB`, that value will be synchronised in `this.props.thing`. React will handle all the Component/prop updates.

That all being said, I genuinely think there's nothing wrong with using an action creator/reducer.

Answer (score 0):

setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

[Refer documentation for more about setState()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Even if he used the callback method, he's trying to access a component local state from within `mapStateToProps`, which uses the global state store.